# RJava Apache POI Excel (XSSF) Remove Picture

Tags: java, r, excel

I'm having trouble removing an image from an Excel document using the xlsx library. There's no built-in method (just addPicture), but you can call arbitrary Java command via RJava to the Apache POI library.

I can remove the actual picture data:

```
library(xlsx)

workbook = loadWorkbook("Book1.xlsx")
pictures = workbook$getAllPictures()
image = pictures$get(as.integer(0))
packagePart = image$getPackagePart()
package = packagePart$getPackage()
parts = (package$getParts())
# Index 7 is "Java-Object{Name: /xl/media/image1.png - Content Type: image/png}"
image_ref = parts$get(as.integer(7))
package$deletePartRecursive(image_ref$getPartName())
```

However, that doesn't remove the *relationship* in the sheet. The Excel file is smaller (no longer contains the image), but when I open it there's a large missing image spot with a "This image cannot currently be displayed" message.

In theory the relationship should have been removed - [deletePartRecursive removes relationships](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#deletePartRecursive(org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartName)) - but if you call `image_ref$hasRelationships()` you get FALSE. For some reason it isn't populated.

That led me to believe I just needed to remove the image relationship. I can do this by grabbing the drawing object that describes the relationship (since there's nothing in the file) -

```
drawings = parts$get(as.integer(6))
drawings$clearRelationships()
```

That (appears) to remove the relationship, but when I call saveWorkbook nothing happens.

Ditto if I navigate to the drawing object in any other way, e.g. via the sheet:

```
sheet = workbook$getSheetAt(as.integer(0))
sheet$getRelations()
[1] "Java-Object{[Name: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawing+xml]}"

refs = sheet$getRelations()
refs$get(as.integer(0))
drawing_object = refs$get(as.integer(0))
```

Unfortunately drawing_object is a member of [XSSFDrawing](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html) which lacks any remove methods. And any combination of does XSSFPictureData, PackageRelationship or remove methods taking them as arguments do not seem to work.

Am I missing something obvious here? How do I remove a picture relationship in Excel?

Thanks.